# Difference between Get Method and Set Method in Class

Tags: php, oop

The book I am learning from says while not always necessary it is generally considered good practise to have a getter and setter method.

With that being said the methods in each example works fine when I initiate an object and pass a value to the method.

So I was just wondering what is  the difference between the following

**Example 1**

```
Class Something{
  public $email;
      function getEmail($newEmail){
        return $this->email = $newEmail;
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
Class Something{
   public $email
   function setEmail($newEmail){
     $this->email = $newEmail
   }
   function getEmail(){
    return $this->email
    }
}
```

**Example1**

```
  $obj = new Something();
    echo $obj->getEmail('example@exaple.com'); //prints email address
```

**Example 2**

```
$obj->setEmail('example@example.com')
$obj->getEmail()//prints email adress
```

I fail to see why the extra step is necessary in example 2, perhaps it is because I am (very) new to OOP & PHP. I just thought it was important to know the difference before continuing since my book does not really elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't always wan't to get and set an email at the same time

A setter is for setting a value, and a getter for getting one.(as the name would suggest)

Sometimes you need to only change the value for example with your email. Someone updates their email and redirects to a new page where they don't see their email. You would only have to set the new email using `setEmail($email)` but you wouldn't need to get it.

Also the other way around, sometimes you only need to get something (of which you don't already know the value). For example, you get on your user profile and it needs to display your email. You then use `getEmail()`and to get it. You don't want to first set the email because you already have the value. So you only want to receive it.

So in example 1, you always need to know the email before you receive it. But this wouldn't work if you don't know the email yet.

You could use example 1 as a setter method tho, since it let's you change the value, and you often want to receive it back afterwards.

Tho for good practice, always just use a getter and a setter seperately